# Mock utility function that is being used on script load

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

For simplicity I created a sample app in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mock-utility-function).

The *Hello* component uses a utility function that I need to mock in order to test it.

```js
const hmmm = mockMe();

const Hello = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
    <p>{hmmm}</p>
  </div>
);
```

I tried several ways to mock the function, for example:

```js
import * as utils from '../utils';

describe('Hello component', () => {
    it('should mock the utility function', () => {
        jest.spyOn(utils , 'mockMe').mockReturnValue("Mocked!");
        // render the component and test it
    }
}
```

My problem is that *Hello.js* runs before the test file. So, it executes the utility function before the mock is applied.

The only solution I could think of is to change the component code and move the call to the utility inside the render function. I would like to avoid this change.

Is there a way to mock the utility function and keep the code unchanged?

Comment: You don't seem to `jest.mock` anything. There are various options for interacting with modules on the Jest object: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object

Comment: If I change my code such that the function is being called inside the render function, the mock works just fine. Are you sure I must use jest.mock?
Regardless, adding it didn't affect my test and the mock still doesn't work.

Comment: To anyone who is voting to close as "needs more focus" (or any other reason for that matter) - please leave a comment for what your are missing so that I will be able to improve the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Before using the methods from the `utils` you need to mock the `utils` folder. For example, `jest.mock('../utils');`

Comment: You probably missed this line: `jest.spyOn(utils , 'mockMe').mockReturnValue("Mocked!");`